# ios: how to get the current sample rate when an action happens

Tags: ios, get, sample, rate

I refer to the pitch detector project

(http://demetrimiller.com/2011/01/25/pitch-detection-in-ios-4-x/)

The sample rate is set as 44100.

My question is that if I have an action in time A, how can I get the current number of sample rate it is in?
I mean, the action A happens in the Ath frame.
How can I get the date?

Thanks very much!

+

My project is to measure the distance between two cellular phone using ultrasound.

Device A sends a 18kHZ sound to device B, and once B detects a frequency higher than 18kHZ, B sends back the same sound to A.

I cannot just get the local time to calculate the distance because there's a huge error. Hence I try to work on sample rate.

Since the sample rate is 44100, there are 44100 samples, from the first to the 44100th.

So I am wondering how can I know which sample it is when the device detects the 18kHZ sound.

Comment: I think you should be much more clear with your question ..:(

Comment: I just add some description. Is that clear enough??